# Download platform specific animation nodes 2.0

Tags: animation-nodes

I've looked high and low and can not find the platform specific (win64) precompiled AN 2.0 download described in the release notes. 
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases

Answer (score 1):

The platform specific variations of Animation Nodes 2.0 can be found while viewing this release of the add-on via its Github page: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.0